# How to determine the size of a recorded audio file

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, avaudiorecorder

I want to display the size of an audio file in a `UITableView`. I recorded the audio with:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

NSDictionary *recordSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithFloat: 44100.0], AVSampleRateKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatAppleLossless],  AVFormatIDKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                [NSNumber numberWithInt: AVAudioQualityMax], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey, nil];
```

I saved the file in the Documents folder, and I'm displaying the name in a `UITableView` cell.

How do I display the size of the audio file as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:URL error:&attributesError];

NSNumber *fileSizeNumber = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileSize];
long long fileSize = [fileSizeNumber longLongValue];
```

Note that the fileSize won't necessarily fit in an integer (especially a signed one) although you could certainly drop to a long for iOS as you'll never exceed that in reality. The example uses long long as in my code I have to be compatible with systems with much larger storage available.